# Backbone Model Save with Specific Attributes, How to Post some attrs when syncing?

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I've got a new model with tons of attributes.
When `#save`ing i expect backbone to `#POST` because the ID is null, this works correctly.

```
$ = require('jquery')
- = require('underscore')

model = new Backbone.Model({
  id: null,
  name: "tom",
  cat: false,
  dog: true,
  //... many more attrs
  whiskers: false,
  tail: true
});
```

Now I want to only send a small subset of attributes to the server on that POST.

With jquery i can write this:

```
data = _.pick(model.attributes, 'name', 'dog', 'tail');
$.post(model.url(), data);
```

How can I do this with Backbone?

I did it with sync below, but it felt wrong.

```
data = {}
data.attrs = _.pick(model.attributes, 'name', 'dog', 'tail');
model.sync('create', model, data)
```

Comment: It is perfectly ok to use Jquery within Backbone. I usually encapsulate the extra functions I need on the model object itself. `model.saveChangeSet(data)`

Comment: You can also check out the `patch` option to send only the attributes that changed on save; you have to pass all the data elements on the save for it to work correctly. `model.save(data, {patch: true})

Comment: or you could override the `sync` method of your model and do whatever you want in it